# How to write an Impala query

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to write a Impala query.

I have two tables - one containing **holiday list** from *2018 to 2022* and second where I have **sales** data with *month start and end date*. I have to write a query where I should be able to get a new column in sales table with holiday date (if my holiday date falls between start and end date then there should be that specific holiday date). Also, if there are two holidays coming in particular month then we have to mention both dates with '|' separator.

Holiday table -

[image]

Sales table -

[image]

Expected output -

[image]

I am using below query:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    case when h.fest_date between a.month_start and a.month_end then h.fest_date
         else ''
    end as holiday_date
FROM sales a
JOIN holiday h
```

Comment: Please update your question with some sample data and the result you want to achieve - added as editable text rather than screenshots, links, etc

Comment: Do you store dates in char/varchar columns?

Comment: @NickW i have added the input table and expected output.

Comment: @jarlh i am storing date as varchar

Comment: Why varchar? Doesn't Impala have a date data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on right track. You need to use `group_concat` to concatenate and then a group by.

```
SELECT a.prod, a.sales, a.start_date, a.end_date,
group_concat(holiday_date,"|") holiday_date  -- it will concat the holdays with a pipe seperator
FROM 
(SELECT a.prod, a.sales, a.start_date, a.end_date,
case when h.fest_date between a.month_start and a.month_end then h.fest_date end as holiday_date
FROM sales a
JOIN holiday h on h.fest_date between a.month_start and a.month_end
) a
group by a.prod, a.sales, a.start_date, a.end_date
```